# My sed code worked... but I have no idea why. Can someone help me understand?

Tags: design-patterns, file-io, sed

I am trying to delete in a file, lines that does not contain two separate terms. I got it to work, but not sure how it worked.

```
sed -i '/^HETATM/!{/^ATOM/!d}' file
```

can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sed line will remove all lines that not starting with `HETATM` or `ATOM`

```
'/^HETATM/!   #if the line is not starting with HETATM, continue to process
{/^ATOM/!d}'  #then we come here, if the line is not starting with ATOM, Del the line
```

I would write in this way:

```
sed  '/^A\|^B/!d'
```